# Specific Linux application loses Synergy connection

Tags: linux, connection, synergy, packet-loss

I have a Synergy setup with Win 7 as the host and CentOS 5.5 Linux as a client.  Everything works great in general...I can smoothly move between the two environments with my single mouse and keyboard.

But then I launch a particular Linux application and the mouse pointer immediately "freezes".  I have lost Syngery connectivity between the two machines.  I then use the Linux box's physical keyboard/mouse to check things out.  Synergyc is still running.  If I kill and relaunch Synergy with the problem application still running, Synergy works until I move the mouse pointer over one of the that application's windows, at which point I again lose the Synergy connection.

I have the source code to this application, but I don't know too much about it.  It's an old X Windows/Motif application. I don't know much about that area either.  Conceivably, I could fix the problem application's code to not cause this problem, but I don't even know where to start in terms of trying to do this.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to how I might go about fixing this?  Are there any other known cases of this problem?  Any idea what the application would be doing differently than most such that it causes this problem?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what could cause Synergy to drop out because a particular application is focused.  You will probably have to run the Synergy server in debug mode and watch the output when the problematic program is focused.  It might shed some light on what's happening from Synergy's point of view.

Possibly some sort of super-grab that prevents Synergy from injecting input events.